# Loss line breaks on getting a file by FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp

There is a text file with line breaks on server:

```
1
2
3
```

I try get him by FTP and show on form:

```
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://x.x.x.x/test.txt");
    request.UseBinary = false;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
```

But in spite of "UseBinary = false" i'v get:

```
123
```

If I get this file by cmd with ascii mode, that file looks fine (contains "\n"). What's wrong?

Comment: [Known Issues with Transfer Mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks) When downloading a file with Windows line-endings (CR+LF) in a text/ASCII mode, the server replaces LF with CR+LF, resulting in an incorrect CR+CR+LF.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava But that won't explain loss of line breaks, quite on the contrary.

Comment: @Telepnev I cannot reproduce your problem. What is an exact contents of the file byte-by-byte, when downloaded using binary mode? `BitConverter.ToString(new WebClient().DownloadData("ftp://login:password@x.x.x.x/test.txt"))`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "31-32-33" by your method, no "0d-0a". Results is same for binary and ascii.

Comment: And if you download the file using (GUI) FTP client in binary mode, how large is it after the download?